# frida.TransportError: the connection is closed

Tags: android, python, malware, frida

I ran Python `1.py` I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 5, in 
pid = device.spawn(["com.example.a11x256.frida_test"])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/frida/core.py", line 98, in spawn
return self._impl.spawn(program, argv, envp, env, cwd, stdio, aux_options)
frida.TransportError: the connection is closed
```

And I have mentioned the result of adb devices in the following:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

And frida-PS -you is coming in the following

```
PID Name 
55 adbd
6051 android.process.acore
5968 android.process.media
5877 com.android.browser
5472 com.android.deskclock
6025 com.android.dialer
4386 com.android.inputmethod.latin
4440 com.android.launcher
4423 com.android.phone
6134 com.android.sharedstoragebackup
4529 com.android.smspush
4236 com.android.systemui
5926 com.android.vending
5709 com.example.a11x256.frida_test
6076 com.google.android.gm
4681 com.google.android.gms
.
.
.
```

The frida works fine but I have some trouble when using automation with Python
and my Python is 2.7 and when I have used python3 with 1.py I got this following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 2, in
import frida
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frida'

And my 1.py file is in the following too

```
#python code
import frida
import time
device = frida.get_usb_device(1)
pid = device.spawn(["com.example.a11x256.frida_test"])
device.resume(pid)
time.sleep(1) #Without it Java.perform silently fails
session = device.attach(pid)
script = session.create_script(open("s1.js").read())
script.load()

#prevent the python script from terminating
raw_input()
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting frida server on the device seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering indicates that the Python script can't find the `frida` module. This issue is likely because you are using different versions of Python (2.7 and 3.x) and the `frida` module may not be installed for both versions.

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the `frida` module is installed for the Python version you intend to use. You mentioned that your script works fine with Python 2.7, so let's focus on that version.

First, make sure you have `pip` for Python 2.7 installed. You can install it if it's not already by following the instructions specific to your operating system.

Once you have `pip` for Python 2.7, you can install the `frida` module for that version by running:

```bash
pip install frida
```

This should install the `frida` module for Python 2.7, and you should be able to run your script with Python 2.7 without any issues.

If you want to use Python 3.x with the `frida` module, you should install it separately for that version using:

```bash
pip3 install frida
```

After installing the `frida` module for Python 3.x, you can run your script with Python 3.x without encountering the "ModuleNotFoundError."

In summary, the key is to ensure that you have installed the `frida` module for the specific Python version you want to use. You can have `frida` installed for both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x on your system without conflicts.